# JQuery - can't implement input user mask

Tags: jquery, html, input, mask

I try to implement input user mask via that [lesson](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#usage) and can't run it. It doesn't work.

My .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      jQuery(function($){
         $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body id="" onload="">
    The following example is a demonstration from the usage tab.
    <table border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Date</td>
          <td><input id="date" tabindex="1" type="text"></td>
          <td>99/99/9999</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do i do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't included the plugin script file.

```
<script src="<path here>jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You are right. But i met another strange thing. After including this file it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ExiRe Make sure you have added the plugin script AFTER the jquery scripts.

Comment: And i checked that all files are include (via firebug).

Comment: `<script src="jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` won't work. You need a full url for the fiddle.